# Wordpress Responsive theme, logo displays different in browsers

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Im a beginner when it comes to building a site. Thats why i choosed to build with Wordpress.

The thing is that i got i responsive theme that should work with any browser.

I upload a logo by going to appearance>Customize>upload logo.

With Crome it looks great:

[image]

But with firefox, Iphone safari and IE it looks bad:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/838/8tl2.png

I've a Childtheme, and the only code i've put in is to get the logo to display a bit more towards the middle:

```
    @import url("../realia/style.css");

.logo-wrapper { position: relative; left: 10%; }
```

Why is it looking like this, ive tried with .clearfix codes and to change the image height etc.

Have a great day and thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out the site: http://bit.ly/1akopZL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `height` from your,

```
.logo class
```

`Height` is causing issue on Chrome as well, while resizing the window. Image is not able to resize. So, remove the height in `px`.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. I feel a bit "noobie" and stupid but where do i find this? I checked out the .css file and removed height etc. But it still look the same. Can I put a code in main .css file to over wright it??

Comment: I managed to remove, height and float: left; from .logo class. Now it looks good in firefox and IE but it still looks bad in the phone.

Comment: U are missed media query for mobile. devices i think. ""
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
/* Styles */
.logo{max-width: 50%;} /*Resize the logo to 50% fit mobile devices*/
}""

Comment: Hi, now it looks better in mobile device. But it still is a pushed a bit to the right, the toggle menu and logo.

Comment: If you look the logo is a bit larger I used following code in CSS: #header-wrapper #header #header-inner .navbar .navbar-inner .logo { float: none !important; height:auto !important; }
And i used your code aswell.

Comment: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/854/b3a1.png
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/577/h8lr.png

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked your theme out, and noticed this class:

```
#header-wrapper #header #header-inner .navbar .navbar-inner .logo {
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Remove the height: 90px and it should look good in all browsers!

Comment: In style.css or header.php? Thank you for your anwer!!

Comment: I managed to remove, height and float: left; from .logo class. Now it looks good in firefox and IE but it still looks bad in the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left` from the logo.

e.g:

```
   #header-wrapper #header #header-inner .navbar .navbar-inner .logo {
       height: 90px;
       line-height: 90px;
       margin: 0;
   }
```

Comment: removing float will not solve the issue on mobile devices check by resizing browser window on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced this issue when my logo was not showing up properly in internet explorer, try with this code hope this will work.

```
max-height: 100% !important;
```